# Нужно ли тире в предложении? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, тире, смысл

*Отлынивать от работы — не по-пионерски*.

Нужно ли тире в этом предложении? По какому правилу мы тут используем тире?

Answer (score 2):

Процитирую [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94).

> **1.** Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен. Ср.:
> *Ходить — долго не мог* (‘лишен был возможности передвигаться в течение длительного периода, например после тяжелой болезни’); *Ходить долго — не мог* (‘не мог заниматься длительной ходьбой’);
> *В случае нужды — прошу* (‘в случае нужды прошу обратиться ко мне’); *В случае нужды прошу* (‘обращаюсь с просьбой, когда испытываю нужду’).
> Такое тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять любую часть предложения...

**Отлынивать от работы — не по-пионерски.**
Смысл: у пионеров принято хорошо работать, а не отлынивать.
При отсутствии тире возникает комическое значение предложения (как будто можно отлынивать от работы и по-пионерски).

P. S. В конце предложения необходима точка.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а какая грамматика у этого предложения?

Answer (score 2):

***Отлынивать от работы — не по-пионерски.***

Правило известное — постановка тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым **при отсутствии глагольной связки.**

В общем случае тире (пауза в устной речи) служит "разделителем" между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого, если такой разделитель нужен. Обычно он требуется в тех случаях, когда сложно определить **структуру** предложения, в том числе отличить предложение от словосочетания.

Правило: Розенталь, [§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91), пункт 5.

При наличии паузы между главными членами предложения тире ставится между подлежащим, выраженным **неопределенной формой глагола**, и сказуемым, выраженным **предикативным наречием на -о (категорией состояния)**: Уступить — позорно (Тендр.)...

В заданном предложении в роли предикатива выступает наречное сочетание "не по-пионерски."

Comment: Но у нас ведь нет никакого наречия на **-о**.

Comment: А предикативное наречие на СКИ вас никак не устроит? Разницы вроде бы никакой. Да и не мог Розенталь всю конкретику расписать, здесь принцип важен. А вот в вашем ответе даже грамматика не обозначена, да и сама тема интонационного тире к этому предложению не подходит

Comment: В категории состояния, мне кажется, нет слов на "-ски".

Comment: Ладно, оставим многострадальное наречие на СКИ  в покое и заменим его синонімом. Отлынивать от работы –  нехорошо.  Теперь  у нас уж точно категория состояния. Типичный такой моральный предикатив.  Кстати, именная часть сказуемого.  Следовательно, это тема "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым", а не "Интонационное тире". Какие у вас причины не ставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, если подлежащее выражено инфинитивом. И вообще говоря, постановка знаков препинания начинается с определения грамматики предложения, вам ли это надо говорить.